# how to handle error handling with iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, error-handling

In the iFrame documentation on mdn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#error_and_load_event_behavior) it states that the error event wont be fired off. Was wondering, how would one go about handling errors that might occur during the rendering of an iFrame, if something like `onError` isnt supported by some browsers anymore?

Comment: `by some browsers anymore` - when you say "some", you mean ALL modern, right - as to what you want to do. The documentation says no error event is fired, did you expect the documentation is wrong?

Comment: @JaromandaX who said anything about the documentation being wrong

Comment: it was a question - you say `in the iFrame documentation on mdn here it states that the error event wont be fired off` therefore, your code can't know when there's an error to handle, so one can't go about handling errors that are never known

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle the error in the iframe and then use `postMessage()` to let the parent page know things didn’t work out in the iframe.